# Application crashes when saving managed object context

Tags: macos, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My app gets crashed when saving the  managedobjectcontext of core data.

Crash log follows below :

```
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [182]
Responsible:     Neat [9540]
User ID:         835384806

Date/Time:       2014-10-15 18:55:11.890 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  B7542E2A-7E0A-9BF4-4026-642BC0899AEA

Sleep/Wake UUID: D3DA262A-ADFC-4D46-8793-1153578CC1D2

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff87619097 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff8ad8f797 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _processReferenceQueue:] + 1575
2   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff8ad969f7 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 3575
3   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff8ad6e5c4 _performRunLoopAction + 372
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff838a4d67 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff838a4cd7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff83895e94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 340
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8501aa0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8501a685 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 173
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8501a5bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a1f224e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a1f189b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a1e599c -[NSApplication run] + 553
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a1d0783 NSApplicationMain + 940
14  com.neatreceipts.nrm            0x000000010edd6cc4 0x10edd5000 + 7364
```

Can anyone please suggest me what might me the problem and how can I resolve this.

Comment: There's not enough information. `SIGSEGV` implies memory corruption of some type. If you add some detail about what your code is doing, it might be possible to be more specific. But this question is not answerable as written.